# what are the inputs to a wavenet?

Tags: text-to-speech

I am trying to implement TTS. I have just read about wavenet, but, I am confused on local conditioning. The original paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03499.pdf), explains to add a time series for local conditioning, [this article](https://medium.com/@evinpinar/wavenet-implementation-and-experiments-2d2ee57105d5) explains that adding mel spectrogram features for local conditioning is fine. As we know that Wavenet is a generative model and takes raw audio inputs to generate high audio output when conditioned,

my question is that the said mel spectrogram features are of that raw audio passed as in the input or of some other audio.

Secondly, for implementing a TTS the audio input will be generated by some other TTS system whose output quality will be improved by wavenet, am I correct to think this way??

Please help, it is direly needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Mel features are created by actual TTS module from the text (tacotron2 for example), than you run vocoder module (Wavenet) to create speech.

It is better to try existing implementation like Nvidia/tacotron2 + nvidia/waveglow. Waveglow is better than wavenet between, much faster. Wavenet is very slow.